# How can I add an error message when user does not enter text into second line of multiple line textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I need to add an error message to the textbox when the user no key in into the second line, but the code that I try also no work for me.i already try text.lenght, line.count and so on

```
Private Sub MeanButton_Click_2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MeanButton.Click

    If Not InputNumberTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MeanCalculateForm.Show()
        MeanCalculateForm.InputNumberListBox.Items.AddRange(InputNumberTextBox.Lines)
        MeanCalculateForm.ResultListBox.Items.Clear()
        Me.Hide()
    Else

        MsgBox("Please enter more number to calculate")
    End If
End Sub
```

picture screenshot :
https://ibb.co/58cd7YC

Comment: It should be obvious that `TextLength` is irrelevant because you could have one long line or multiple short lines.  `Lines` is the obvious option.  It is a `String` array so a `Length` of 1 means one line and anything greater means multiple lines.

Comment: so i need add InputNumberTextBox.TextLength = 1 to it?

Comment: You'lll have to add a validation proc for the input, to verify whether the *numbers* are correct. When you do, count the validated `InputNumberTextBox.Lines`. If the count is `> 0`, you're mostly ok (except, eventually, for the numbers that didn't validate).

Comment: InputNumberTextBox.Lines.Count = 1 ,this answer suitable for me now

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own function to check whether a `String`, in this case `InputNumberTextBox.Text` contains a valid number like this:

```
Private Function IsValidNumberFromText(ByVal Input As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim Check As Integer = CInt(Input)
    Catch Ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

Then just do:

```
If IsValidNumberFromText(InputNumberTextBox.Text) ...
```

This assures that the `String` only contains a valid number.